# Is there a way in Python to open a gmail email in browser?

Tags: python, gmail, imap

What I'm trying to achieve is a script where given a Gmail account, it can open a random unseen email in browser, like a random winner pick.
I'm starting with this code:

```
import email
import imaplib

m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com",993)
rc, resp = m.login('myemailaddress','mypassword')
```

I know we can retrieve for example all unread email, but I've found NOTHING to get the Gmail URL in order to open this url within browser.
Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I don't think that it's possible at all. IMAP server *(normally)* shouldn't have any connection to HTTP.

Comment: You can use the [IMAP GMAIL Extensions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions) to get a X-GM-MSGID.  You might be able to construct a URL to the message using that by looking at what URL you get clicking on an email, but in general, Google doesn't provide that sort of access to their webmail.

Comment: Alright, thanks for these useful informations :)